# Slidetoggle jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Olá, como eu faço para dar slideToggle em uma div cada vez que clicar em um span com jQuery.

O projeto é um dicionário que precisa ter palavras e descrições separadas.

Cada palavra tem uma descrição, então quero que ao clicar em uma determinada palavra em uma lista, abra a descrição da mesma.

Eu quero tornar dinamico o reconhecimento da palavra que to clicando que corresponda a descrição da mesma. Descrição vai estar com display none e quero exibir a partir do clique no span que é a palavra

codigo html a baixo

```
<div class="palavraSingle">
 <span>Palavra para clicar</span>
  <div class="palavraDescricao">
     <p>Ea ex dolor velit culpa fugiat velit aliqua dolor consequat eiusmod pariatur excepteur elit sed duis esse magna ea.</p> 
 </div><!-- palavraDescricao -->
 </div><!-- palavraSingle -->
```

codigo jQuery a baixo:

```
var palavra = [$('div.palavraSingle span')];
var descricao = $('.palavraDescricao');


for (var i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
    palavra[i].click(function(){
        descricao.slideToggle();
    })

}
```

até agora tentei varios jeitos, esse foi o ultimo tentado.

Comment: Importante [editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/548494/como-dar-slidetoggle-em-uma-div-a-partir-de-um-clique-no-span) para adequar ao site. Para evitar duplicação de informação vou passar mais umas orientações no campo de comentários de lá.